# Selecting Folders and editing .ini files with batch script

Tags: batch-file, ini

I have about 500 folders or so. Each of them have .ini files that are with default values.

What I want to do is paste these lines in them (if they don't exist)

```
[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]
Prop2=31,Title of the Folder
Prop3=31,Subject
Prop4=31,Publisher
Prop5=31,Tag1,Tag2,Tag3;
Prop6=31,Comment
```

But there are multiple folders with the same properties in the code as mentioned above. So First i want the batch script to ask to select the folders and then ask for the values after Prop2, Prop3, Prop4, Prop5 & Prop6 and then copy the string values of the properties along with the above code to the .ini files of the selected folders and copy the contents as above if they don't exist.

Comment: I would suggest you consider a different scripting method to batch files, or at least consider using non native tools for such a task.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).